# htaccess rewriting to sef url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url from http://xyz.edu/profile.php?name=gavin to http://xyz.edu/gavin.html

Sample code:

```
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?compname=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: I have placed the htaccess in the root of my website.

Comment: That's not what I mean. You need to show your current rules and what attempt you've made in your question.

Comment: RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?compname=$1 [L]

Comment: @PanamaJack please see now

Answer (score 0):

Well it's about the same rules you already have. Try this and let me know how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ profile.php?compname=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I did a work around Jack, and it worked well. Thanks for the help.